# LightSwitch screen data changed event

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm testing a HTML Client project, I have a Main screen to list all the items, now I'm trying to add a label to show the total count of items using a data item local property, it worked for the first time, but if I add or delete item, it doesn't refresh the count, I could not find any screen event or query event to handle this. below is my current code, it worked only the first time:

```
myapp.Main.created = function (screen) {
// Write code here.

myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.OrdersForUser().execute().then(function (results) {
    var TotalCountOfOrders = CountOrders(results);
    screen.TotalOrdersForCurrentUser = TotalCountOfOrders.toString();
});
```

};

Thanks for your help

Comment: Reffer this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/479cbc96-6ec2-4d9f-b2f8-a2b43a09111e/html-client-dynamically-count-records-in-a-collection-on-browse-screen?forum=lightswitch

Answer (score 0):

```
myapp.BrowseCustomersByCountry.created = function (screen) {
    screen.Customers.addChangeListener("state", function () {
        if (screen.Customers.state === msls.VisualCollection.State.idle) {
            screen.CustomersCount = screen.Customers.data.length;
        }
    });
};
```